# MacBook Pro a1502 - Cannot start unless magsafe is connected - power is 100%

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, magsafe

I have just upgraded the battery on my MacBook a1502, and everything worked fine for a few weeks.

But now when I close the screen down for sleep for more than a few hours, I have to connect the power adapter (MagSafe) or it will not power on.

When the macbook pro has turned on, I can disconnect the power adapter again, and it will keep battery for hours without any problems.

I have not tried to shut down, and see if this happens in this state also??

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a Late 2013, 13" MacBook Pro? Did you upgrade the battery yourself? Have you performed an SMC reset? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295

Comment: Hi. Yes I did change the battery myself (This was the second time I did this), last time there was no issue. I have tried to reset the SMC according to the link, now I will see tomorrow if this has helped. Thank you so far

Comment: Let's see what your power manager log reveals for the duration of time between sleep and poweroff. Please reproduce the poweroff behavior, then after you reboot run the command `pmset -g log`, copy **just the portion** of time from shortly before you initiated sleep till after the unexpected poweroff & reboot, and edit your question by appending a *code block* (see Stack Exchange help for markup info) containing the log excerpt.

Comment: I will try to get this information